# API .net core with list how to show badrequest custom message when the Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] List<T>? request) is not a list or array?

Tags: .net-core

The trouble with this is that I have this post:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] List<TabAccesos>? request)
```

but when you try in Postman a body without `[]` the error that show is:

```json
errors": {
        "$": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[nombreproyecto.Models.TabAccesos]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 5."
        ]
```

and I need to change that errors message but when enter to that post don't go to the catch, execute a badrequest before enter. How to solve this?

We'll need to show a badrequest message that is custom like JSON is not in the correct way or something like that because the client doesn't want to show names of the tables or project.

```
 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[nombreproyecto.Models.TabAccesos]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has been occured because of invalid model state. You can configure globally modal state errors as below

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
    {
        var errors = context.ModelState.Values
            .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
            .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
            .ToList();

        // Customize the error message
        var customErrorMessage = "Invalid model state. Please check your input.";

        // Combine the custom error message with the original errors if needed
        var finalErrorMessage = $"{customErrorMessage} Errors: {string.Join(", ", errors)}";

        var result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new
        {
            message = finalErrorMessage
        });

        return result;
    };
});
```